# cannot access property within the same class

Tags: c#

I'm having trouble understanding why a part of my code can't resolve another part.

I have this class that contains two properties. The second property relies on the first, but it keeps throwing this error:

> cannot resolve symbol 'yearlyEmployees'

```
public class Financials
{

    public static IEnumerable<SalaryEntity> yearlyEmployees = FactoryManagement(12345);


    //cannot resolve symbol 'yearlyEmployees'
    public static IEnumerable<CompanyEntity> YearlyGroup(IList<yearlyEmployees> allExempt)
    {

    }

}
```

I'm sure there's an easy answer, but I just can't find it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`yearlyEmployees` is a variable name, not a class name. Try:

```
public static IEnumerable<CompanyEntity> YearlyGroup(IList<SalaryEntity> allExempt)
```

Answer (score 1):

That is because you don't have a type of `yearlyEmplyee` - that is your variable.

Instead:

```
public static IEnumerable<CompanyEntity> YearlyGroup(IList<SalaryEntity> allExempt)
{ }
```

And then just pass a collection of `SalaryEntity` to the function. If you always want to process only `yearlyEmployees` (which I don't think is the case but not sure) then just call it from within the method `Financials.yearlyEmployees'.

Answer (score 1):

You must use the type SalaryEntity as item for your list.

```
public static IEnumerable<CompanyEntity> YearlyGroup(IList<SalaryEntity> allExempt) {}
```